# Using for loop to remove elements from a list is not working, but using list comprehension is fine

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

OK, this problem is actually solved, but I still want to know **WHY**. I am trying to remove elements from a 2-dimensional array, and here's the code:

```
print("adj in the while loop: ", adj)
for z in adj:
    print("for loop: ", z)
    if z[-1] is True:
        adj.remove(z)
result += 1
print("adj after all execution: ", adj)
```

Console Output:

```
adj in the while loop: [[1, True], [0, 2, True], [1, True]]
for loop: [1, True]
for loop: [1, True]
adj after all execution: [[0, 2, True]]
```

This doesn't work as intended. The correct output after the execution should be `[]`.

So I start to edit the code using list-comprehension.

Code for list-comprehension:

```
adj = [z for z in adj if z[-1] is not True]
```

It worked as intended. The output is `[]`.

This confuses me. Why would these two seemingly identical methods yield different results? Can anyone explain that to me?

Comment: You should not remove from list while iterating over. In the latter case, you select items from list matching criteria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two methods are not identical. In the list comprehension, you never call `adj.remove(z)`.

The list comprehension is creating a new list as it iterates over `adj`, then you assign that (empty) list back to `adj` once it's done. It doesn't change `adj` while iterating, only after the last iteration.

Comment: I get that. So why shouldn't we use the `remove` method while iterating over to change a list? Is this not suggested or "forbidden" in Python?

Comment: @Z.Richard When you iterate over the list with a for loop, Python keeps track of which element the loop is accessing with an internal counter. By removing an element as you go through the loop, you're making the loop skip the next item. (Check out the note in the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#for)

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely use `.remove()`, but iterate over a copy of the original and not the original itself:

```
adj = [[1, True], [0, 2, True], [1, True]]

for z in adj[:]:
    print("for loop: ", z)
    if z[-1] is True:
        adj.remove(z)
result += 1
print("adj after all execution: ", adj)
```

which prints out an empty list.

Here, we iterate over the copy, but remove elements from the original. This avoids discrepancy that you see with your code.

Comment: That's awesome, but this can be very disturbing for those who know very little about Python. Is this a kind of a "bug" in Python?

Comment: @Z.Richard, this is not a bug. Python for loops work this way. When you remove elements inside, for loop may skip element resulting in unexpected behaviour. By making the iteration and removal on different objects, this discrepancy can be avoided. Sorry for a late reply.

Answer (score 1):

Iteration over the `list` and at same time with it's inner block, if you use method `remove` or `append` for an element is not right way to do it. Basically better to change the coding to other way. As like Austin suggested in his code or use separate index instead of iterative index or element.

That is

```py
adj = [[3, 4, 5, False], [8, 7, False], [0, True], [-1, False], [1, True], [0, 2, False], [0, 2, True], [1, True], [4, False]]

del_index = 0
for i in range(len(adj)):
    print("for loop: ", adj[del_index])
    if adj[del_index][-1] is True:
        adj.remove(adj[del_index])
    else:
        del_index+=1
print("adj after all execution: ", adj)
```

Filter can applied for this purpose

```py
filter(lambda elem: elem[-1] is True, adj)
```

This may crash your system since the append element to the list and same time iterating over the same.

```
crash_my_system = [0]
for i in crash_my_system: crash_my_system.append(i+1)
```

This is not only true for `List`. this is common to all mutable data structure such as `Dict`. Refer: [Christoph Zwerschke's blog](https://cito.github.io/blog/never-iterate-a-changing-dict/)