# Appending list of dictionaries with an additional key in one dictionary and a nested dict as its value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a schema, and I have a list of nested fields that should be in it.
Basically, what I have is:

```py
[{'name': 'a', 'type': 'string'}, 
{'name': 'b', 'type': 'string'}, 
{'name': 'c', 'type': 'string'}, 
{'name': 'd', 'type': 'string'}, 
{'name': 'e', 'type': 'string'}, 
{'name': 'attr', 'type': 'string'}, 
{'name': 'f', 'type': 'string'},
{'name': 'g', 'type': 'string'}, 
{'name': 'h', 'type': 'string'}, 
{'name': 'i', 'type': 'string'}, 
{'name': 'j', 'type': 'string'}, 
{'name': 'k', 'type': 'string'}]
```

But when the "name" is "attr", I want to add another dictionary k-v pair to it, with the key as "fields" and the value as another nested list of dictionaries in the same format as the one above. This will make it look like:

```py
[{'name': 'a', 'type': 'string'}, 
{'name': 'b', 'type': 'string'}, 
{'name': 'c', 'type': 'string'}, 
{'name': 'd', 'type': 'string'}, 
{'name': 'e', 'type': 'string'}, 
{'name': 'attr', 'type': 'string', 'fields': [{'name': 'aa',....}], 
{'name': 'f', 'type': 'string'},
{'name': 'g', 'type': 'string'}, 
{'name': 'h', 'type': 'string'}, 
{'name': 'i', 'type': 'string'}, 
{'name': 'j', 'type': 'string'}, 
{'name': 'k', 'type': 'string'}]
```

Below, the master_schema_set and the nestedschemaset were both just sets that I converted.

```py
finalschema = [{'name':l} for l in master_schema_set]
finalschemanested = [{'name':l} for l in nestedschemaset]

for i in finalschema:
    i.update({"type":'string'}) #all types will always be string
    for item,val in i.items():
        if val == 'attr':
            i.update({'fields':finalschemanested})
```

Running this gives me an error "dictionary changed size during iteration," but ultimately that's what I want. What is a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
for i in finalschema:
    i.update({"type":'string'}) #all types will always be string
    if i['name'] == 'attr':
        i.update({'fields':finalschemanested})
```

- Note: as the error states do not try to update dict while iterating the object.

Answer (score 0):

modifying `i` while iterating over its key/value pairs is forbidden, a workaround is to iterate over his keys only, and update `i`, like this:

```
for i in finalschema:
    i.update({"type":'string'})
    for val in i.keys():
        if i[val] == 'attr':
            i['fields'] = finalschemanested
```

this, however, is modifying the dict while iterating over and it's not a good idea. If there's a better way to do what you want you better consider a little refactoring.

In your case, you don't need to iterate over i at all, and change your code to something like this:

```
for i in finalschema:
    i["type"] = 'string'
    if i['name'] == 'attr':
        i['fields'] = finalschemanested
```

On a side note, you are making code prone to fall in a python gotcha: `i.update({'fields': finalschemanested})` is going to put the same `finalschemanested` object in every dict you are updating. In case you do this operation more than once, you have the same exact object in two different places, meaning modifying one place will lead to a (probably unwanted) modification in the other place(s). Consider using the `copy` module:

```
from copy import deepcopy
... 
       i.update({'fields': deepcopy(finalschemanested)})
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating the `Dict` and changing over to the same `Dict` is not the good idea. Refer: [Christoph Zwerschke's blog.](https://cito.github.io/blog/never-iterate-a-changing-dict/)

You need to change your code out of this kind of pattern. This is true for list and other data structure. in python2, it never show up as error or warning and looping run through endlessly. 
Refer one of my answer [Raja Sakthiyan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56940289/11726178)